# Smart contract unpredictable gas for seemingly simple method

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, gas-estimate

I'm having an issue where a method that seems straightforward is showing a huge amount of gas requirements. I tried to run it from the verified polygonscan UI and metamask tells me it can't estimate the gas (which I take to mean it's incredibly high). I can't understand, though, what it could be?

Here is some of the code in question:

```
mapping(address => bool) private players;
uint256 public playerCount;
event PlayerRegistered(address player);

function register(address _player) public onlyOwner {
   require(players[_player] != true, "Player already registered");
   players[_player] = true;
   playerCount += 1;
   emit PlayerRegistered(_player);
}
```

I must be missing something huge about mappings or public variables, otherwise this seems so straightforward.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: It is working fine on my end. The code looks fine.

Comment: Seems an issue with the way I was calling it, perhaps. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was actually the way I was calling the function, and the gas question was more of an estimation red herring.